# Why is this node-csv-parser event listener never firing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I want to read a large csv file line by line, parse the tab separated values into a javascript object, then do stuff with that object. That's the general workflow.

I can read the raw file, but for some reason `node-csv-parser`'s `readable` event is never firing. I see lots of `string == ...` log messages, but no `parser readable` messages.

```
import csv from 'csv';
import byline from 'byline';
import {createReadStream} from 'fs';

var readStreamByLine = byline(createReadStream(file));
readStreamByLine.on('data', function(chunk) {
  var string = chunk.toString();
  console.log('string == ' + string);
  var parser = csv.parse({
    delimiter: '\t'
  });

  parser.write(string);

  parser.on('readable', () => {
    console.log('parser readable');
    while (csvdata = parser.read()) {
      console.log(csvdata);
    }
  });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you don't need byline.  by default the csv parser will return a line at a time when you're streaming it. look at the examples https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse/blob/master/samples/stream.js

Comment: right, but if I have a really large csv file, won't the entire file's raw contents be stored in memory? I want to avoid that, if it's practical.

Comment: the streaming parser should be streaming it from disk so it shouldn't be loading the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: the csv streaming parser doesn't have entire file in memory, but won't the stream returned by `createReadStream` return the entire `file` in its buffer, and store that buffer in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution. I had neglected to add the last line from the [example](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/examples/):

`parser.end();`